# Godot extensions c++ modules vs android modules. What is the difference?

Tags: android, c++, plugins, godot

Looking at the c++ extension tutorial on godot wiki everything makes perfect sense except the separation dealing with android modules:
http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/creating_android_modules.html

What exactly is the difference between creating a regular c++ godot extension and creating an android extension using the guide above? I thought you can simply create your c++ extension and compile for godot for android the normal way with your c++ extenstion like so:
http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/compiling_for_android.html

Comment: I believe the issue is that when you need to use native android libraries.

When you develop c++ modules, you can statically compile everything and make it usable on android. If you need to access android native toolkit or the play store, you have to use the android JNI.

Comment: I see. Its hard to verify this as its not anywhere in the documentation

Comment: The whole point of Java JNI is for c++ code to call java managed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a C++ Module is an extension to the Godot Engine that helps us add more features to the Godot Engine.

Whereas an Android Module is also for adding a way to interface between Andriod and C++ code of the engine. As written in the docs and I quote,

> On Android, interfacing with C++ through JNI (Java Native Interface)
>   isn’t as convenient.

So Andriod Modules will/should help you set up ads, analytics, notifications and more in Godot games.